# Dispersion equation with variable wavenumber

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, dispersion

The wave equation
$$u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$$ is known to have a simple wave solution $u(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ where the dispersion equation is simply $c=\omega/k$. Yet, let the wavenumber be a function in $x$, then the independent variable $x$ will appear in the dispersion solution cause the first and second derivatives are functions in $x$ as the following:
$$ \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} = (ik+ixk_x) e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$ and $$ \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} =  \left( (ik_x+ik_x+ixk_xx) + (ik+ixk_x)^2 \right) e^{i(kx-\omega t)} .$$
then $$c^2=\dfrac{-\omega^2}{(2ik_x+ixk_xx)+(ik+ixk_x)^2}$$
Did anyone encounter an independent variable as $x$ explicitly in the dispersion relationship as in the terms $ixk_x x$ and $ixk_x$?

Comment: "Is it normal... and what does it mean?" Is probably either too opinion-based or too vague to receive a good answer on this forum. But, good luck.

Comment: I did not encounter any dispersion equation with the independent variable; for me, this is odd. Just, I am wondering if anyone has encountered something like that before.

Comment: If you just want an example of where this occurs in any area of physics you could, for example, Google for the "WKB Approximation"

Comment: I did, yet I could not get some useful regarding my question on the dispersion equation.

Comment: @Kernel I edited my answer. Try to have a look at it, and check if I managed to do no mistakes during my computations. P.S.: in your original question, you missed some curly brackets for the second derivative of $k$, i.e. $k_{xx}$, in the last two equations

Comment: Not exactly the same due to the lack of $x$ dependence, but complex dielectric functions have a complex dispersion, e.g. $\epsilon(\omega)\sim1/(\omega_0^2-\omega-i\gamma\omega)$ where $\omega_0$ is a resonant frequency and $\gamma$ a retarding constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, $u(x,t) = A e^{i(kx-\omega t}$ (with $c= \omega/k$) is a solution of the equation. The problem is in supposing that:

$$\tilde{u}(x,t) = A e^{i(k(x)x-\omega t}$$

is also a solution of the same equation, that step does not seem justified, in fact, *for almost any choice* of $k(x)$ we will not have a solution in the strict sense. The most general solution formed by plane waves would be a generalized linear combination of the type:

$$u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A(k) e^{ik(x - ct)}\ \text{d}k$$

Given some function $k(x)$ there is no guarantee that you could found a function $A(k)$ such that:

$$e^{i(k(x)x-\omega t)} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A(k) e^{ik(x - ct)}\ \text{d}k$$

Comment: Thanks, why do you think that we cannot have a solution for any pattern of $k(x)$? Is that also apply to the dispersion equation?

Comment: Observe that the generalized linear combination is a form of Fourier transform (FT), but FT can be defined for functions which satisfy $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\oplus L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but for most choices of $k(x)$ this condition it is not satisfied. Of course, you can find some FT outside this domain but usually the FT is a distribution, not a proper function.

Comment: Thanks, the wave solution with variable k: $e^{i(k(x)x-\omega t)}$ could satisfy the equation proposed by @basics  below and the dispersion relations would have terms like $x$ as mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal to encounter...

It is difficult to answer "is it normal?" Normal to whom? That being said, in my opinion, this is not normal/typical.

> and what does it mean?

No one can answer "what does it mean?"

No one can answer because you have posited some **arbitrary** function of $x$ that you just happen to be calling "$k$". No one knows what this arbitrary function is, so no one can tell you what it "means."

---

In the comments I suggested a more complete example (with more context) wherein:
$$
k(x)=\sqrt{2m(E-V(x))/\hbar^2}\;,
$$
where $E$ is a particle's energy, and $V(x)$ is the potential it sees.

With this additional context, I can, for example, point you to the WKB approximation, where you can try to glean some physical meaning.

But, if you just have some arbitrary function:
$$
k(x) = ??????
$$
no one can provide a physical meaning.

---

**Update: OP has edited their post to remove the two above-quoted questions. So I will update my answer...**

OP's new question is:

> Did anyone encounter an independent variable as $x$ explicitly in the dispersion relationship as in the terms $ixk_x x$ and $ixk_x$?

You will likely not encounter such a spatial dependent "dispersion relationship" unless you are trying to force plane waves to be a solution to a problem not solved by plane waves.

All one can do is provide examples. Above, I provided the example of the WKB approximation.

Another example to consider is the propagation of waves through bulk materials with an interface. This is similar to the one-dimensional problem of a wave travelling along a rope whose linear density $\mu$ depends on position. Suppose, for example, the rope is made up of one heavy rope (with linear density $\mu_1$) and one light rope (with linear density $\mu_2$) joined at a knot. Far from the knot the dispersion relation is either:
$$
\omega = k\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu_1}}
$$
or
$$
\omega = k\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu_2}}\;,
$$
which could be though of as a spatially dependent dispersion relation.

As discussed above, I can provide some examples and discuss their meaning. But, given that OP's $k(x)$ is some unknown/arbitrary function, it is not possible to discuss a particular physical meaning.

Comment: Thanks, I just meant by the independent variable the $X$ itself and not $K$ or any wave parameters; I do understand their meaning. I am asking about the appearance of $X$ here $$ c^2=\dfrac{-\omega^2}{(2ik_x+ixk_xx)+(ik+ixk_x)^2}$$. All dispersion  equation that I saw did not include any $x$ or $y$

Comment: By the notation $k_x$ do you mean the derivative of $k$ with respect to x, or do you mean the x-component of $\vec k$?

Comment: The derivative of k with respect to x. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: That's what I thought. So, what is the functional dependence of $k$ on $x$? This is the part that you have not specified. It could be **anything**.

Comment: Yes, this could be anything, and I did not think about the form of the $k$ itself. I think the form of $K$ is problem/application specific. $K(x)$ is sometimes called local wavenumber (fluid dynamics).

Comment: Yes, this is the point. It is problem/application specific. So how is anyone supposed to tell you what it "means" if it has a different meaning for different problems/applications?

Comment: I not asking about the meaning of $k$ or its derivative. I am asking about the appearance of $x$ explicitly in the dispersion equation (e.g, $xk_x$ in $ c^2=\dfrac{-\omega^2}{(2ik_x+ixk_xx)+(ik+ixk_x)^2}$).

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematical point of view your idea does not make sense. Remember that plane waves do not exist, they are just a tool that physicists introduce to build up a mental representation. Ask a mathematician; he will tell you that to get a dispersion relation, you just need to take the Fourier transform of your wave equation. But (x,k) is the pair of variables involved in the Fourier transform. They can only appear together in: $ e^{i(k.x-\omega t)}$. with k being the Fourier variable independent of x.

Comment: The idea of a local wave number ( wave number that varies with x, y,z) is already accepted and used at least in the field of fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar solutions in studying hydrodynamic (in)stability.
These solutions, usually in the form of traveling waves $\phi(x,t) = A e^{i(k(\omega)x - w t)}$, appear in the study of **weakly nonlinear instabilities** in open flows as the solution of weakly nonlinear approximation of the equations of motion, and not as the results of the linear wave equation.

Now, I can't really remember if I've ever seen the dispersion you wrote in your answer, but I'll leave a list of references here where you can have a look by yourself:

- Huerre, Rossi *Hydrodynamic instabilities in open flows*, 1998.
  *(not easy to found, if you have no access to university library, and maybe even if you have it)*
- Charru, *Hydrodynamic Instabilities*
- Drazin, *Hydrodynamic Stability*

You can also look for *Landau-Ginzburg equation*, that usually results from the weakly nonlinear approximation of nonlinear equations of motion in fluid mechanics, and other fields, and it's a mathematical model often used for introducing and exploring weakly nonlinear instabilities.

If you give us some details about your field of study, maybe someone could give you more precise suggestions.

**EDIT: Wave function with the desired solution**

It seems to me that the function $\phi(x,t) = A e^{i(k(x)x - \omega t)}$ is the solution of a the following PDE with non uniform coefficients, that goes into the wave equations in uniform media when coefficients are uniform, reading

$\dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \dfrac{\omega^2}{\kappa(x)'} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \dfrac{1}{\kappa(x)'}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \right) = \dfrac{\omega^2}{\kappa(x)'^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \dfrac{\omega^2 \kappa(x)''}{\kappa(x)'^3}  \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$,

having defined $\kappa(x) := k(x) x$, and their derivatives
$\kappa(x)' = k(x) + k(x)'x$,
$\kappa(x)'' = 2 k(x)' + k(x)'' x$.

**EDIT 2**: performing a change of variable $y(x)$ so that $y'(x) = k'(x)/ k_0$, and $\partial/\partial y = k_0 / k'(x) \, \partial/\partial x$ you get the classical linear wave equation in $y$, $t$ independent variables.

Maybe this can help the imagination or the memory of someone, to think at an example where this kind of equation is used.

Comment: Thanks, I am a meteorologist. I used the wave equation cause I thought that this is the simplest equation to discuss my point. Your $k$ is a function in $\omega$, yet I am talking about instances when $k$ is a function in the independent variables $x$ or $y$. I encountered before solution with the WKB approximation, yet I have never seen such a dispersion equation that includes $x$ or $y$ or $z$ variables. Those are not characteristics of the waves that may happen to appear in the dispersion relationship.

Comment: Maybe, a similar relation can come from a linear problem with coefficients that are not uniform in space. Give me some time, and I'll try

Comment: Done. I don't consider myself as a "reputable source", but you can double-check the calculations, and let me now if you find the same results. If we both agree, it's something better than nothing

Comment: Thanks, the wave solution satisfy the PDE you listed above, thanks for your efforts. Are you a ware of any specific application for this. I was interested to see the kind of application that use such dispersion equation with explicit independent variable $x$.

Comment: The bounty expires in 6 days, if i did not see new specific responses from the community, I will accept your answer. Also, I am not quit sure if I can accept more than one answer. Thanks!

Comment: In spare time, I'll try to think some possible application for this. And wait to see if anyone else has some idea about it. Can I know how you came out with this expression?

Comment: Could you please rephrase that? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: How did you think at a function with that expression (wave with wavenumber depending on the spatial coordinate $x$)? I'm just curious, not to make controversy

Comment: In fluid dynamics and particularly in atmospheric sciences, decay of gravity waves is associated with changes in the wave properties (e.g., wave number ) like when  waves approaches critical layers. The idea looks odd but it happens… Google gravity wave critical layers. If you are interested in math you will enjoy atmospheric dynamics

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. As soon as I have some spare time for some insight (or if I move to work as a meteorologist in the meanwhile), I'll take a look at it

Answer (score -1):

Since you have only one wave $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}=cst$, so $k_{x}=0$ ,  your formula is simpler : $$c^{2}=\frac{-\omega^{2}}{(ik)^{2}}$$
i.e.$$k=\frac{\omega}{c}$$

Note: the last relation gives:
$$(2+x^{2})k_{x}i=k+xk_{x}-\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}$$

$k(x)\in \mathbb{R}$, for the equation to be homogeneous,
in the left side of the equation  $k_{x}(x)$ must be pure imaginary, CONTRADICTION.

PS: The only theory i know that takes into account the variation of the frequency,length, vector,...., of wave with the variable space (height x) is general relativity: Einstein's shift https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: Thanks, if $k$ varies with $x$, then the pattern can not be represented by only one wavelength ($\lambda$ should be $\lambda_{avg}$.

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector , if m(0)=0 , we find the previous  relation {for light-like/null}.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Yet not sure what this has to do with current problem?

Comment: Ok, for k(x)=2pi/lambda(x), take the function y=sin(x²) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%28x%5E2%29 is that a wave?

Comment: $k$ is function in $x$, the simplest case is $k=cst$.

Comment: I will expose my physical common thread: an electromagnetic wave in a graviational field, we know that the frequency (f(x)=1/T(x)= ....) changes with height (i.e. h=x), the wave is described by Einstein's equations, i.e. with tensor calculus.